# implicit rule not run although its depedency is missing

Tags: makefile

I have a Makefile similar to this:

```
.PRECIOUS: do/%.build

do/%.install: do/%.build
    touch $@

do/%.build:
    touch $@
```

My intention is that all do/*.install targets depend on the do/*.build target, and that the rule for the build target is run if the stamp file for the build target is missing, and that the install target is run if the build stamp is newer. This works fine during the first run:

```
$ make do/foo.install
touch do/foo.build
touch do/foo.install
```

It also works fine if the build stamp is newer:

```
$ touch do/foo.build 
$ make do/foo.install
touch do/foo.install
```

However, it doesn't work as intended if the install stamp is present and the build stamp is missing:

```
$ rm do/foo.build 
$ make do/foo.install
make: `do/foo.install' is up to date.
```

The install target is not run. What should I do? Does this have something to do with the fact that I have to add the .PRECIOUS line to avoid the automatic deletion of the build stamp?

Regards,
Tino

Answer (score 0):

From [the manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Chained-Rules):

"If an ordinary file b does not exist, and make considers a target that depends on b, it invariably creates b and then updates the target from b. But if b is an intermediate file [i.e inferred from a pattern rule], then make can leave well enough alone. It won't bother updating b, or the ultimate target, unless some prerequisite of b is newer than that target or there is some other reason to update that target."

There are a couple of ways to solve this problem, but I know of no really clean way. Do any other targets depend on the `build` or `install` files?

Comment: There are other targets that depend on the `install` files.